# React Native environment setup issue, Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager

Tags: react-native

I am trying to setup react native environment and want to run default page or any message on my emulator but getting this error:

```
`Build file 'D:\projects\react native app\Native Environment\AwesomeProject\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager`
```

I am just following official documents provided by react native
there is some information, what setup I did

- Node and openjdk8 installed using chocolatly
- jdk-8u11 is installed and JAVA_HOME environment path is set for the same
- android SDK platform 29 is present
- ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set for SDK
- running project by npx react-native start and npx react-native run-android

Now I really don't know why this build failure is happening, I have Googled it but could not reach on the solution.
I'm new in react-native

Answer (score 1):

After so much googling and uninstalling-Reinstalling everything, I figured out the issue.
This issue is related to JDK bundle version which I was using before.
Actually, I manually installed JDK package from oracle instead of using openJDK which was advised at the official page [Here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) .
so now my new environment variable JAVA_HOME is pointing to the openJDK.
Before:

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11
```

Now

```
JAVA_HOME  C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\openjdk-8u292-b10
```