# Why I am getting this exception: Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager

Tags: java, flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

I am using VS Code. All other projects are working well. I am running project on real device with command "flutter run" from terminal. Why I am getting this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where:
>   Build file 'C:\Users\hp\Documents\flutter-mobile-app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>   Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager

This is my app/build.gradle

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        disable "Instantiatable"
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.otobucks.app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
}
```

**This is my android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**My java home, before this I was using jdk 1.8.0_291**
[image: java home path]

and my gradle properties:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you changed the Java version?

Comment: I think the java SDK is compatible or corrupted https://stackoverflow.com/a/68330970/7670665 check this answer

Comment: @SoloWolf93 you probably mean **in**compatible?!

Comment: @AliPunjabi could you add more debug output? I think you can run `flutter doctor` to get more insights or run the gradle command directly `gradlew assemble --stacktrace` (or similar)

Comment: @Patrick I was updating everythingg to match my colleague system cos I was gettting exception

Comment: @dpr you can check here all outputs with different gradle and kotlin versions and plugin:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/115477

Comment: @SoloWolf93 should I have to download the openjdk manually or any other way?

Answer (score 3):

There can be a Problem with classpath build gradle version so you can change the version and try to match it with google services version:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```

Comment: Hi Meet, welcome to SO! Next time, please use code instead of screenshots in the future :)

Comment: best solution down grade 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0' to 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15' it will work

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'` and run the app

If the problem persists, please create a new app with the following and provide the logs

It should work be sure your java version is up to date not old like java8 or 9

Comment: tried 4.1.0 but still not working

Comment: the same error?

Comment: it should work be sure your java version is up to date not old like java8 or 9

Comment: Why say "thanks in advanced" in an _answer_ post?

Comment: why not to say  "thanks in advanced".